# how to get api data in select box with query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made a table with select boxes using an api.
my goal is to display the borders data in the div when it's selected but I can figure out how
here's what I have so far:

```js
$.getJSON(" https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function(countries) {
  let ul = $("<ul>");
  let sel;

  $.each(countries, function(index, oCountry) {
    sel = $("<select>");

    $.each(oCountry.borders, function(index2, border) {
      sel.append($("<option>").html(border));
    });

    ul.append($("<li>").html(oCountry.name + " ").append(sel));
  });

  $("#div1").empty();
  $("#div1").append(ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="borderDiv">display borders</div>
<div id="div1">countries</div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to give a clearer description of the issue. The code which you added to the question, which I edited in to an executable snippet, appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change `sel = $("<select>");` to `sel = $("<select class='border' data-country='"+oCountry.name+"'>");`
- Also use `sel.append($("<option>").val(border).html(border));` instead of `sel.append($("<option>").html(border));`

Now the `<select>` has class border and has `data-country` attribute which holds country name .. And the `<option>` has a value of the border

- Then add `<select>` change event `$(document).on('change' , 'select.border' , (e) => {`

```js
$.getJSON(" https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function( countries) {
    let ul = $("<ul>");
    let sel;    
    $.each(countries, function(index, oCountry){
        sel = $("<select class='border' data-country='"+oCountry.name+"'>"); //<<< Here
            $.each(oCountry.borders , function(index2, border){
                sel.append($("<option>").val(border).html(border)); //<<<< Here
            });
            ul.append($("<li>").html(oCountry.name + " ")
              .append( sel ));
    });
    $("#div1").empty();
    $("#div1").append(ul);
});

$(document).on('change' , 'select.border' , (e) => {
  console.log('country: '+$(e.target).attr('data-country')+' -Border: '+$(e.target).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="borderDiv">display borders</div>
<div id="div1">countries</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a change event on dropdown value changes. Firstly you need to add a class in dropdown and then you can call jQuery code to get selected values and then can place it in any div as below:

```js
$.getJSON(" https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function(countries) {
  let ul = $("<ul>");
  let sel;

  $.each(countries, function(index, oCountry) {
    sel = $("<select class='borderDd'>");

    $.each(oCountry.borders, function(index2, border) {
      sel.append($("<option>").html(border));
    });

    ul.append($("<li>").html(oCountry.name + " ").append(sel));
  });

  $("#div1").empty();
  $("#div1").append(ul);
});

$(document).on('change', '.borderDd', function() {
  $("#selectedBorder").text($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="borderDiv">display borders</div>
<div id="div1">countries</div>
<div id="selectedBorder"></div>
```